# Fixing broken rows from txt file using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am a complete novice to programming. I am trying to parse and format 'broken' rows (rogue lf's in the file instead of the \cr\lf windows format) in a txt file. Using python 3.4 and reading these types of posts I have managed to read the source files and create a file with only the broken rows in it with all the lf's removed so its one long line. Now I need to read the line and count the delimiters which are in this format '<|>' and after the 36th one add a newline then continue counting the next 36 and add a newline etc. I have tried a few different things but have got stuck as I am not sure if I need to .tell() then .seek() to insert the \n. Any suggestions as to how to insert the newline char after the 36th delimiter please?

```
my_count = 36 # define the number of delimiters to count
LineNumber = 1 # define line counter 
FileName = 'Broken_Registrations.txt'  # variable to define filename
target = open('Target.txt','w',encoding='utf-8') # open a file to write fixed lines
with open(FileName,encoding="utf8") as file:
    for line in file:                            # open file read
        cnt=line.count('<|>')                    # count delimiters
        if cnt == mycount:                       # count until mycount then
            target.write(line).append("\n")  # write line and append new line char
print('DONE!')  # let me know when you finished         
target.close() # close the file opened outside of the with
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i managed it, it was simple all along, although there is probably a much more efficient way to do it but this worked for me

```
#import pdb
#pdb.set_trace()
my_count = 36
LineNumber = 1 # define line counter 
FileName = 'Broken_Registrations.txt'  # variable to define filename
target = open('Target.txt','w',encoding='utf-8') # open a file to write fixed lines
with open(FileName,encoding="utf8") as file:
    for line in file: # open file read
        cnt=line.count('<|>') # count delimiters
        if cnt == my_count: # count until mycount then
            line = line.rstrip() # remove whitespace
            target.write(line +"\n") # write line and append new line char
print('DONE!')  # let me know when you finished         
target.close() # close the file opened outside of the with
```